# split svg with one path into multiple paths

Tags: html, svg

I have SVG of a human body, that SVG all in one path, I want to split that SVG into multiple paths

[image]

so that I want the head to be a separate path and also the same for each hand and also for each leg and the upper half of the body

here is my SVG code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg 
    id="Layer_1" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    viewBox="0 0 159.6 425.57">
    <defs>
        <style>
            .cls-1{fill:#fcd4c5;}
        </style>
    </defs>
    <path 
        class="cls-1" 
        d="M159.37,228.66c-1.21-1.08-2.96-3.76-4.44-8.33-1.48-4.57-7.8-6.72-9.54-10.21-1.75-3.5-3.09-14.25-3.23-25.81-.13-11.56-2.42-24.87-4.44-30.65-2.02-5.78-4.03-12.1-3.36-19.36,.67-7.26,.4-14.52-.54-18.28-.94-3.77-1.35-3.5,.13-11.16,1.48-7.66-1.48-16.13-6.05-24.2-4.57-8.07-14.38-8.2-16.94-10.08-2.56-1.88-7.53-2.96-12.23-5.65-4.71-2.69-7.8-3.49-7.8-5.38s-.14-6.86,1.74-10.89c1.88-4.03,1.88-8.06,1.88-8.06,2.01,1.08,2.15-.81,3.9-4.44,1.75-3.63,2.29-6.05,1.88-7.93-.4-1.88-2.15-1.61-2.15-1.61,0,0,3.09-11.7-2.96-19.22C90.42,1.38,83.1,.26,80.35,.05V0s-.2,0-.55,.01c-.35-.02-.55-.01-.55-.01V.05c-2.75,.21-10.06,1.33-14.89,7.34-6.05,7.53-2.96,19.22-2.96,19.22,0,0-1.75-.27-2.15,1.61-.4,1.88,.14,4.3,1.88,7.93,1.75,3.63,1.88,5.51,3.9,4.44,0,0,0,4.03,1.88,8.06,1.88,4.03,1.75,9.01,1.75,10.89s-3.09,2.69-7.8,5.38c-4.71,2.69-9.68,3.76-12.23,5.65-2.55,1.88-12.37,2.01-16.94,10.08-4.57,8.06-7.53,16.53-6.05,24.2,1.48,7.66,1.08,7.39,.13,11.16-.94,3.76-1.21,11.02-.54,18.28,.67,7.26-1.34,13.58-3.36,19.36-2.02,5.78-4.3,19.09-4.44,30.65-.13,11.56-1.48,22.32-3.23,25.81-1.75,3.49-8.07,5.64-9.54,10.21-1.48,4.57-3.23,7.26-4.44,8.33-1.21,1.08,2.55,3.09,4.3,0,1.75-3.09,2.96-4.7,4.03-4.17,1.08,.54-.4,6.18-1.75,12.1-1.34,5.91-2.69,9.81-.27,9.81s4.03-9.01,4.7-10.89c.67-1.88,.54,4.57-1.21,9.14-1.75,4.57-1.34,6.05,0,6.32,1.35,.27,2.69-3.76,2.69-3.76,0,0,2.62,2.06,5.4-5.09,0,0,2.78,1.99,5.36-6.16,2.58-8.14,4.57-18.87,3.57-23.83-.99-4.96,11.32-26.61,12.71-45.09,1.39-18.47,3.97-32.77,4.96-33.77,.99-.99,6.75,17.48,4.37,27.21-2.38,9.73-2.58,14.5-2.78,16.29-.2,1.79-3.38,9.14-4.37,17.28-.99,8.14-4.57,16.88-1.39,45.09,3.18,28.2,8.34,37.54,8.94,43.3,.6,5.76,.6,20.86,.4,23.84-.2,2.98-1.19,7.15-1.39,10.33-.2,3.18-4.96,14.3,.4,36.35,5.36,22.05,6.55,34.76,6.55,37.14s-1.19,2.78,0,5.96c1.19,3.18-3.17,9.9-6.42,12.62-3.25,2.72-4.48,4.83-4.92,6.23-.44,1.41-.26,2.9,.88,2.9,0,0-.53,1.14,.35,2.37,.88,1.23,1.93,.79,1.93,.79,0,0-.09,1.41,1.32,1.76,1.41,.35,2.02-.09,2.02-.09,0,0,.79,1.58,2.37,1.49,1.58-.09,1.93-1.32,2.11-2.19,.18-.88,.7-2.72,1.58-2.81,.88-.09,1.41,.7,1.06,1.49-.35,.79-.53,1.32-1.06,2.55-.53,1.23,.7,2.9,4.04,2.28,3.34-.62,1.93-3.78,3.95-5.97,2.02-2.19,2.9-3.95,2.81-7.11-.09-3.16,3.42-2.55,2.9-8.08-.53-5.53-1.67-7.11-.61-10.1,1.05-2.98-.7-6.5-.88-7.9-.18-1.4,.08-14.66,.68-18.44,.6-3.77,2.78-16.69,2.38-21.85-.4-5.16,2.58-9.14-.4-22.05-2.98-12.91,1.79-11.32,1.59-24.63-.2-13.31,3.38-17.67,2.58-29.99-.79-12.31,1.59-19.06,1.99-25.82,.28-4.74,1.14-6.45,1.64-7.04,.68,.55,1.67,2.1,1.93,6.45,.39,6.76,2.18,14.1,1.39,26.41-.79,12.32,1.59,16.69,1.39,29.99-.2,13.31,4.57,11.72,1.59,24.63-2.98,12.91-1.19,16.88-1.59,22.05-.4,5.16,2.98,18.08,3.58,21.85,.59,3.77,.86,17.03,.68,18.44-.18,1.41-1.93,4.92-.88,7.9,1.05,2.99-.09,4.57-.61,10.1-.53,5.53,2.98,4.92,2.9,8.08-.09,3.16,.79,4.92,2.81,7.11,2.02,2.19,.61,5.36,3.95,5.97,3.34,.62,4.57-1.05,4.04-2.28-.53-1.23-.7-1.75-1.06-2.55-.35-.79,.18-1.58,1.06-1.49,.88,.09,1.41,1.93,1.58,2.81,.18,.88,.53,2.11,2.11,2.19,1.58,.09,2.37-1.49,2.37-1.49,0,0,.61,.44,2.02,.09,1.4-.35,1.32-1.76,1.32-1.76,0,0,1.05,.44,1.93-.79,.88-1.23,.35-2.37,.35-2.37,1.14,0,1.32-1.49,.88-2.9-.44-1.41-1.67-3.51-4.92-6.23-3.25-2.72-7.62-9.44-6.42-12.62,1.19-3.18,0-3.57,0-5.96s1.19-15.1,6.55-37.14c5.36-22.05,1.79-33.17,1.59-36.35-.2-3.18-1.19-7.35-1.39-10.33-.2-2.98,.99-18.08,1.59-23.84,.59-5.76,5.76-15.09,8.94-43.3,3.18-28.2-2.78-36.94-3.77-45.09-.99-8.14-1.79-15.49-1.98-17.28-.2-1.79-.4-6.55-2.78-16.29-2.38-9.73,3.37-28.2,4.37-27.21,.99,.99,3.58,15.29,4.97,33.77,1.39,18.47,13.71,40.12,12.71,45.09-.99,4.97,.99,15.69,3.57,23.83,2.58,8.15,5.36,6.16,5.36,6.16,2.78,7.15,5.4,5.09,5.4,5.09,0,0,1.34,4.03,2.69,3.76,1.34-.27,1.75-1.75,0-6.32-1.75-4.57-1.88-11.02-1.21-9.14,.67,1.88,2.28,10.89,4.7,10.89s1.08-3.9-.27-9.81c-1.34-5.92-2.82-11.56-1.75-12.1,1.07-.54,2.28,1.08,4.03,4.17,1.75,3.09,5.51,1.08,4.3,0h0Z"/>
</svg>
```

is there is a visual online tool to help me achieve this, or any other way or steps that I can follow to achieve this?

Comment: either redraw it or figure out where the bits of the path correspond to the bits you want by loading it into an SVG editor.

Comment: Since its a single path, you can paste the path into: https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/ Round it to 0 decimals then convert to Absolute path... then cut/paste what you need